# Clarification of Baire category theorem: a (counter-?)example

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, the-baire-space

I am trying to understand the statement of [Baire's category theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem).

Why is $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n := \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \big[(n, n+\frac{1}{2}) \cap \mathbb{Q}\big] = \emptyset$ dense in $\mathbb{R}$? As I understand $\mathbb{R}$ is a complete metric space and for each $n$, $A_n$ is an open dense set in $\mathbb{R}$, which would yield the claim by Baire's theorem. But it does not seem in accordance with any conceptual idea I have of a dense set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the issue here is confusion over the definition of a dense set.

A subset $S$ of $X$ is dense $X$ if every point in $X$ is either an element of $X$ or a limit point of $S$.

It should be clear here that none of the $A_n$ here are dense in $\mathbb R$, because $-1$ is not in any $A_n$, nor is a limit point of any $A_n$.

Answer (score 1):

$[n,n+\frac 1  2)\cap \mathbb Q$ is not dense in $\mathbb R$. It is only dense in $[n,n+\frac 1  2)$. It is also not open.

Comment: What about $(n, n + \frac{1}{2})$. It is open in $\mathbb{R}$. Is it only dense in $[n, n + \frac{1}{2}]$?

Comment: Yes, it is dense in $[n,n+\frac 1 2]$ but it is not dense in $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

$A_n=(n,n+\frac12)\cap \Bbb Q$ is neither open nor dense in $\Bbb R$, therefore $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}A_n$ not being dense is perfectly consistent with Baire category theorem.